# Impedir acceso por URL al directorio "app" en Symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony3, symfony

Llevo poco tiempo con Symfony y estoy desarrollando una aplicación.

Todo funciona perfectamente pero me he dado cuenta que puedo acceder a los ficheros de configuración ubicados en "app/config" con solo poner la ruta en el navegador (por ejemplo poniendo http://127.0.0.1/app/config/security.yml).

En el propio "security.yml" tengo definido el control de acceso por usuarios de esta forma:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /panel
            target_path_parameter: /panel
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login

access_control:
        - { path: ^/langAdmin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/config, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, requires_channel: https }
```

Todo esto funciona. No deja entrar a usuarios no logados, y en las zonas definidas que empiezan por "langAdmin" y "config" solo deja entrar a Administradores.

He probado tanto en entorno DEV como en entorno PROD y ocurre lo mismo.

¿Como puedo proteger los archivos ubicados dentro de "app"?

Gracias.

Comment: El directorio `app` no debería estar publicado, sólo `public`. Ya que no has seguido correctamente las instrucciones de uso, puedes crear un archivo `.htaccess` que contengan `deny from all`.

Comment: ¿A qué instrucciones de uso te refieres? Apache está configurado según indica la web de Symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Me refiero a esto: *The web directory serves as the document root when configuring your web server. In the examples below, **the `web/` directory will be the document root**. This directory is `/var/www/project/web/`*. Yo uso la versión 4, veo que tú usas la versión 3. Mi comentario muestra `public` porque es como ahora se llama el directorio `web`, precisamente para indicar que debe ser lo único público. https://symfony.com/doc/master/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Sí, yo tengo configurado el directorio "web" como público. He seguido haciendo pruebas y he conseguido que funcione habilitando los ficheros .htaccess poniendo "AllowOverride All" (uso SSL así que lo he puesto en el Virtual Host correspondiente). Funciona pero me quedo un poco molesto ya que no lo he conseguido hacer funcionar sin el fichero .htaccess.

Comment: El manual indica que configures la directiva `DocumentRoot` de tu apache para que apunte al directorio `web`, por lo que es **IMPOSIBLE** que se pueda acceder al directorio `app` ya que está un nivel por encima. Si quieres seguir exponiendo tu aplicación, usa la solución que te dije más arriba: `Deny from all` en un archivo `.htaccess`.

Comment: No es imposible. Yo lo estaba haciendo sin darme cuenta. Y estaba puesto el DocumentRoot a  "/var/www/html/web". Seguramente será un efecto colateral del SSL pero toda la parte del directorio web funcionaba al pelo pero se podía acceder a los archivos dentro de "app" y todo era porque Apache no le hacía caso a los .htaccess.

Comment: Mira bien tus archivos de configuración de tu servidor apache, es probable que tenga un archivo para los sitios web https.  En mi máquina es `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`. Si modificas el de HTTP (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`) no tiene por qué afectar al funcionamiento de HTTPS. Edito: se pueden ver los archivos que vienen con apache2 por defecto aquí: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/apache2/filelist

Comment: has probado hacer un virtualhost?

Answer (score 0):

Esto es porque actualmente estas trabajando en local, cuando lo subas a un servidor de producción, debes configurar la url de su web a la carpeta web y no a la carpeta que apunte ahora (generalmente htdocs o public_html o algo en esa linea)

Es decir, tu url al apuntar a la carpeta web de symfony no dejara acceder a ninguna de las carpetas que están al nivel de la carpeta web y estará protegido. Por eso es importante poner tus imágenes, css, etc en la carpeta web cuando estés creando tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Creo saber cual es tu problema, tiene que ver con la configuración de tu servidor local, no explicas nada al respecto pero estoy casi 100% que lo que pasa es que las reglas de que se configuran en Apache/Nginx están mal, te dejo un enlace con ejemplos de la documentación oficial:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Solo están en inglés.

Saludos,